# How to retrieve a localized text/caption for standard push button?

Tags: windows, localization, button

I want to add "Yes" and "No" buttons to my window. It's a bit similar to standard MessageBox, so I would like to use localized strings in these buttons. I.e. "Yes" and "No" should be written in OS's current language.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No easy answer. You can try getting a translation glossary from Microsoft, or use thier online translation tool (more on both [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688105.aspx)).

Other "hacks" involve reading the string resources of user32.dll - but this will only work for localized version of the OS (i.e., not if you're using MUI, which sits on top an EN-US version).

I like the online translation or glossary approach as it proofs the app from any future API changes.